# Any way to schedule an event similar to MySQL Events in Django?

Tags: django, events

I have a database event working with my Django application (hosted on apache2) to update a Date field in one of my tables.

This date field influences another column in the table `Inspection_Due?` which returns Yes or No depending on what Date is in the row. I'd like to do more than just update the table here though which is why I'm wanting to move away from SQL Events. I want to be able to send off emails, texts, notifications etc whenever this is changed.

So I wanted to know if there was any existing method of creating a background event in Django without me opening any views to achieve this whenever the Date column in the database is altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Django Celery. Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing.    It is focused on real-time operation, but supports scheduling as well.

Here are first steps for django [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). 
You could create a `post_save` method in your model, where you will run a asynchronous task, which will send off mails as you wish.

For example:

```
@app.task()
def your_celery_task_which_sends_mail(id):
    your_object = YourModel.objects.get(id=id)
    #do stuff, send mails, check if changed

class YourModel(models.Model)
    yourfields...


@receiver(post_save, sender=YourModel)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    your_celery_task_which_sends_mail.delay(instance.id)
```

Comment: So will this work even when I am not accessing any pages from my app or sending any messages?

Comment: Could you be more precise ? This post_save will execute every time your model saves.

Comment: For example if the entire app is not run for a day. Can I have an email still fire off? Basically I'm looking for similar functionality to a database event where it happens as long as the server is running

Comment: Yes you can. Celery is a generic asynchronous task queue. In place of "django_project" you would point to your module. See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application for an example.